# Remove indentation of multiline entries in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have several long figure titles which span over multiple lines in the list of figures. How can I remove the indentation of the first line? I tried `\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{6 em}` but this changes the spacing for all lines of the entry. (see below - NB. I would like to keep the full titles and so using a short title is not an option)

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{6 em}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0 em}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\footnotesize{Fig. }}
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This figure has an extremely long title spanning more than one line in the list of figures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This figure has a short title}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: consider `\usepackage{tocbibind}` to get rid off the `\addcontentsline` there

Comment: I have added a note to my answer regarding this `\addcontentsline`: you have to add a `\clearpage` command before, since otherwise the `\addcontentsline` will be executed on the page of the `\tableofcontents`, but `\listoffigures` will start a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\cftfigfont` is intended for defining the format of the entry, not for adding material. Replace the corresponding line by

```
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Fig. }
```

then the list of figures looks as intended:

[image]

**Note** that you have to precede the `\addcontentsline` for the list of figures by a `\clearpage` command, otherwise the toc entry for the list of figures will show the wrong page number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{6 em}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0 em}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Fig. }
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This figure has an extremely long title spanning more than one line in the list of figures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This figure has a short title}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```