# Inconsistent Indentation for Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I'm getting inconsistent indentation for longer TOC entries.
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Some Text}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{The long title the long title the long title the long title the long title the long title }
\end{document}
```

I'm talking about something similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346690/remove-indentation-of-multiline-entries-in-list-of-figures) question but for the TOC.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you mean with inconsistent indentation and tell us in more detail which output you expect instead. Indenting the first line differently from subsequent lines makes sense, because then your readers can easily tell a continued heading from a new heading in the ToC.

Comment: Probably not related to the question at hand, but `\chapter*{\centering Experiment 1}` is something I'd try to avoid. If you want your `\chapter` headings centred, there should be a way to define that globally in the preamble.

Comment: BTW: Your chances of getting a good answer increase quite a bit if you turn the code snippets shown in the question so far into a compilable example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the issue you are asking about with as little code as possible.

Comment: @moewe I have edited the question. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

With starred sections you need to add `\protect\numberline{}` to get proper alignment.

See https://latexref.xyz/_005caddcontentsline.html

[image: wdf]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{X Some Text}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{X The long title the long title the long title the long title the long title the long title with *, not aligned}

\chapter{Y The long title the long title the long title  the long title the long title the long title, OK}

\chapter*{Z Some Tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Z The long title the long title the long title the long title the long title the long title, with *, aligned}

\end{document}
```